# "Only strings, FileObjects and UploadedFileObjects can be imported" laravel spatie

Tags: laravel

Controller Code

```
 public function store(CreatewallpaperRequest $request)
{

    $post = $this->wallpaperRepository->store($request);

    Flash::success('Wallpaper saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('wallpapers.index'));
}
```

My Repository Code

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $input = $request->all();
    $post = $this->create($input);

    $post->addMedia($file)->toMediaCollection();
}
```

Any one Please Help me To Solve this Error

Comment: Removed () But Still Getting Same Error

Comment: `   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $input = $request->all();
        $post = $this->create($input);

        $post->addMedia($file)->toMediaCollection();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try dumping the $file variable to see what the value is. In my case it came up null due to a naming mismatch between my form and Request-class. Make sure that your $file variable is of the type string/FileObject/UploadedFileObject and that it is named 'image' in your form and your CreatewallpaperRequest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the key is file :

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
```

Second you probably need to insert this column as well :

```
ALTER TABLE `media` ADD `generated_conversions` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL AFTER `responsive_images`;
```